# Integral domain and ordered ring

Tags: group-theory

I know that every ordered ring is an integral domain. Is it true that every ring that is an integral domain is also ordered?

By ordered I mean for any $a \in R$, either $a = 0$ or $ a > 0$ or $a < 0$, and only one of them holds. Also, if $ a,b >0$, then $a \bullet b >0$ and $a + b >0$.

A ring for which $a \bullet b = 0$ implies either $a = 0$ or $b = 0$ is called an integral domain.

Comment: I don't think a finite field can be ordered. If, say $1>0$, then $2=1+1>0$, $3>0$, etc, and you end up with $-1>0$.

Comment: Additionally, I am hesitant to agree with the language "is ordered," because even when a ring *can* be ordered, unless my suspicious is wrong, presumably it could in general be given *different* orderings. The ring doesn't come "equipped" with any one of them, so we don't say it "is" ordered, we say it "can be" ordered.